# How to pass data from a table to input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table listing user names and emails:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Users</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td>admin &nbsp; <div style="visibility: hidden">admin@email.com</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> User1 &nbsp;<div style="visibility: hidden">user1@email.com</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td>User 2&nbsp;<div style="visibility: hidden">user2@email.com </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

First of all, I am not sure if this is a good practice to expose an email with setting visibility to hidden, but the security is not a concern in this case.

The main problem is that once clicked on a user name, or a check box next to it, I would liek the email address to appear in the following box:

```
<input name="data[To]" type="text" id="To"/>
```

I really appreciate your help here!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following will work with your current markup (though it would be nicer to give your table an id to select it with):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table td").click(function() {
        $("#To").val( $(this).find("div").text() );
    });
});
```

That is, on click on any `td`, find the `div` within it and put its content into the `input`. Of course this assumes each `td` will only contain a single `div`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hUXx4/

I would be more inclined to store the data in an html5-style `data-` attribute, e.g.:

```
<td data-email="admin@email.com">admin</td>
```

...in which case you'd use it like so:

```
$("#To").val( $(this).attr("data-email") );
// OR
$("#To").val( $(this).data("email") );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how about if I need to allow a user to click on multiple e-mail addresses and list them all in the input box?

Comment: Well you can append to what's already there with `$("#To").val( $("#To").val() + " " + $(this).find("div").text() );`.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional note to @nnnnnn's answer, it'd be better if you used this:

```
<td data-email="admin@email.com">
```

you can then use jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method, making your code look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table td").click(function() {
        $("#To").val($(this).data("email"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Ha! I was just editing my answer to add that suggestion - I even used the same data attribute name as you. +1.

Comment: @nnnnnn haha. Kinda makes my answer a bit redundant now!

Comment: @nnnnnn not a problem, I'll just delete it in a bit :)